# How would I code an algorithm that does as follow?

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have three arrays of six red numbers ranging from 1 to 6. There can be multiple times the same number.

> For example, [1, 4, 3, 3, 6, 2], [5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4] and [2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 6]

The goal of the algorithm is to turn numbers blue in those arrays following these rules:

- Every blue number has to be unique (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
- Each array should have 2 blue numbers
- The algorithm should warn me if it isn't possible to do so

> In this example, the blue numbers could be (1, 4) in array one, (2, 5) in array two and (3, 6) in array three.

Is it realistic to code an algorithm that could do that? I'm looking for the logic that I could code to make it work.

Comment: R u referring red number and blue number as color of number or anything else ?

Comment: Why the use of spoiler tags?

Comment: @VishalKamlapure it's a way to indicate which six numbers are a valid choice. It could be purple and green if anything.

Comment: There's only 90 possibilities to check, so the algorithm of generating all possible solutions and seeing if any of them are valid is very reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can reduce this problem to bipartite matching.

If we consider two sets of vertices, one for the arrays and one for the numbers, and make an edge between the array A and number n if n is an element of A, then we have a bipartite graph on which we can use [any matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching#Algorithms_for_bipartite_graphs). Then, each match between an array and a number indicates that that number is blue in that array.

This only works for making a single number blue for each array, but can be expanded by adding every array as a vertex twice, thus getting two matches per array and therefore two blue numbers per array.